# How to prevent text scaling when resizing textbox with fabricjs

Tags: angular, typescript, resize, fabricjs, scale

I am new to FabricJs and my concern is regarding resizing the textbox - I have a following solution that enables to resize the Textbox vertically and horizontally, but not at the same time. I´ve been trying to find a solution that does both at the same time without text being resized. Can you please help me find a solution?

Here is a link to my jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/vstefani/s7yfu93w/27/

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
canvas.setWidth(500);
canvas.setHeight(500);

var myText = new fabric.Textbox("Some text", {
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  top: 100,
  left: 100,
  fontSize: 20,
  textAlign: 'center',
  fontFamily: 'Arial',
  padding: 2,
});
canvas.add(myText);

let lastHeight: number;
const updateTextSize = () => {
  const controlPoint = myText.__corner;

  if (controlPoint && controlPoint !== 'mr' && controlPoint !== 'ml') {
    lastHeight = myText.height * myText.scaleY;
  }

  myText.set({
    height: lastHeight || myText.height,
    scaleY: 1,
  });
};

myText.on('scaling', updateTextSize);
myText.on('editing:entered', updateTextSize);
myText.on('text:changed', updateTextSize);
```

Comment: Did you got the solution for this. I am facing them same problem here :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems controlPoint 'mr' and 'ml' are not triggered by 'scaling' event but by 'resizing'.

A solution (working for me) is to add :

```
textbox.on('resizing', updateTextSize);
```